# Trouble Displaying a Product's Price in Stencil Conditional Statement

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm using the Cornerstone theme in BigCommerce. On my product page, I need to hide pricing unless the end user is logged in. BigCommerce has this feature, but it's all or nothing and I only want to restrict certain items from displaying their price. I am using a custom field at the product level named HidePrice. This custom field has either a True or False defined for each product on my site. There are three conditions I need to account for...

1. The end user is logged in: Display the price regardless of what the HidePrice value is
2. The product's HidePrice value = false: Display the product's price
3. The product's HidePrice value = true and the end user is NOT logged in: Suppress the product's price and display an alternate "Too low to show" message.

Here's my code that isn't quite working...

```
<div class="productView-price">
    {{#if customer}}
        {{#if product.can_purchase}}
            <p class="productView-price">
                <span>Price: {{product.price.without_tax.value}}</span>
            </p>
        {{/if}}
    {{else}}
        {{#filter product.custom_fields 'HidePrice' property='name' }}
            {{#if (toLowerCase value) '==' 'true'}}
                <div class="too-low-to-show">This product is priced too low to show!</div>
            {{else}}
                <p class="productView-price">
                    <span>Price: {{product.price.without_tax.value}}</span>
                </p>
            {{/if}}
        {{/filter}} 
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

The piece I can't seem to get working is condition #1 above (The product's HidePrice value = false: Display the product's price). Conditions #2 & #3 work just fine but the price simply never displays when the requirements of condition #1 are met. Oddly, the "Price:" label I've pre-pended just before the price handlebar will display but the price handlebar itself seems to be ignored by BigCommerce. I have found that if I use the same price handlebar outside of my conditional statement, it will render on the page. I'm baffled by this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue here is simply scope. Once you enter the filter condition, you have left the global scope and entered the product.custom_fields scope. You no longer have access to the product object. A simple fix for this should be to go back up a level by appending "../" in front of product.price.

```
<div class="productView-price">
{{#if customer}}
    {{#if product.can_purchase}}
        <p class="productView-price">
            <span>Price: {{product.price.without_tax.value}}</span>
        </p>
    {{/if}}
{{else}}
    {{#filter product.custom_fields 'HidePrice' property='name' }}
        {{#if (toLowerCase value) '==' 'true'}}
            <div class="too-low-to-show">This product is priced too low to show!</div>
        {{else}}
            <p class="productView-price">
                <span>Price: {{../product.price.without_tax.value}}</span>
            </p>
        {{/if}}
    {{/filter}} 
{{/if}}
</div>
```

Comment: That makes too much sense :) Thank you Matt! I will give that a shot and will post my results.

Comment: Note: depending on which version of Handlebars your theme uses, you might need a second "../" (../../product.price...)

Comment: Thanks Matt! Your suggestion worked perfectly. I have it completely functional now, thanks to you :)